# Generating a random string to save as an id, but continues to change on every page refresh?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller

I am trying to generate a Random 4-5 alphanumeric string to replace a standard user id, i have everything working, except every time I refresh the pages it generates and replaces the String. i have tried before_save and before_create but both seem to not work here.

My Model:

```
class Admin < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_create :admin_ident

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable,
         :validatable, :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable

       validates_uniqueness_of :admin_ident

       def admin_ident
         self.admin_ident = SecureRandom.hex(2).upcase
       end
end
```

My Devise Registration Controller:

```
class Admin::Admins::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  private

  def sign_up_params
    params.require(:admin_admin).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirm, :admin_ident, :f_name, :m_name, :l_name, :dob, :street_number, :street_name, :unit_apt,
    :quadrant, :city, :province, :postal_code, :home_tel, :moibile_tel, :office_tel, :office_ext, :company_email,
    :position, :start_date, :end_date, :quit, :resigned, :terminated_cause, :terminated_wo_cause, :medical_leave,
    :leave_of_abscense, :dl_number, :dl_class, :expiry, :conditions, :sl_number, :sl_certs, :issued, :expires, :emc_1_name,
    :emc_1_tel, :emc_1_relationship, :emc_2_name, :emc_2_tel, :emc_2_relationship)
  end

  def account_update_params
    params.require(:admin_admin).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirm, :current_password, :admin_ident, :f_name, :m_name, :l_name, :dob, :street_number, :street_name, :unit_apt,
    :quadrant, :city, :province, :postal_code, :home_tel, :moibile_tel, :office_tel, :office_ext, :company_email,
    :position, :start_date, :end_date, :quit, :resigned, :terminated_cause, :terminated_wo_cause, :medical_leave,
    :leave_of_abscense, :dl_number, :dl_class, :expiry, :conditions, :sl_number, :sl_certs, :issued, :expires, :emc_1_name,
    :emc_1_tel, :emc_1_relationship, :emc_2_name, :emc_2_tel, :emc_2_relationship)
  end

  def set_admin
     @admin = Admin.find_by_admin_ident(params[:id])
  end

end
```

My Routes.rb File:

```
  ## Namespace Resources
    namespace :admin do
      devise_for :admins, controllers: {
        :registrations => 'admin/admins/registrations',
        :sessions => 'admin/admins/sessions',
        :passwords => 'admin/admins/passwords',
        :confirmations => 'admin/admins/confirmations',
        :unlocks => 'admin/admins/unlocks'
      }
      resources :admin_static
    end

  ## Devise Scopes
  devise_scope :admin do
    authenticated  do
      root to: 'admin/admin_static#home', as: 'admin_authenticated_root'
    end
  end
```

not sure where I am going wrong here.. any assistance would be great!

> **Edit 1:**

I am attempting to edit the admin/admin_static#home page

Comment: What page are you refreshing?

Comment: I will edit But I am refreshing the admin/admin_static#home

Comment: It is essentially just a static landing page after login

Comment: Why do you want to do that? What do you try to achieve?

Comment: This is a b2b app for security / patrol management / dispatch the page they land on will provide daily updates but for now it is static

Comment: and the generated ID has been assigned for display as this is their unique identifier to both support and dispatch so it seems fitting to add it to the welcome page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that it might be that you're using the same name for the field and the method that updates the field randomly.

```
before_create :generate_admin_ident
validates_uniqueness_of :generate_admin_ident

def generate_admin_ident
  begin
    self.admin_ident = SecureRandom.hex(2).upcase
    other_admin = Admin.find_by(admin_ident: self.admin_ident)
  end while other_admin
end
```

That should make all of the uses of `admin_ident` refer to the field and not the random generator.

Note that you're also using a validation to ensure uniqueness, however, this can cause arbitrary calls to `create!` or `save` to fail.  Those should either be wrapped in begin..rescue..retry blocks, or the random generator should validate uniqueness itself.

The `begin..end while` loop and the `other_admin` code are intended to manually validate the uniqueness of the `admin_ident` generated by the method, and keep trying until it finds a unique value.

Comment: that was the problem, i removed the generate thinking it would be easier across the board.. Stupid error on my part! thanks much

Comment: Super!  And I added a little bit to the answer, in case it helps track down the next issue.  Hard lesson learned on that validating generated IDs.

Comment: ahh thats excellent, so can I put the validate statement right in the method? that may be a noobish question but i'm a noob lol..

Comment: Unfortunately, no.  The validate is effectively a callback that gets invoked when `create` happens.  You actually need to do the query internally to the method.  I'll update the answer with an example.

Comment: Thats FANTASTIC! thanks much for the added help here! that makes alot of sense now that i see it! much appreciated.

Comment: My utter and thorough pleasure!  Thanks for having something for me to work on that I actually know how to solve!  :D

Answer (score 2):

Presumably you are displaying `admin_ident` on these pages with `some_admin.admin_ident`.

This will update the attribute, since you have replaced the reader method with one that sets admin ident. I would suggest that you call that method `set_admin_ident` instead (and update the `before_create` to match)